# Python MySQL prepared statement to dictionary throws error

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting pull the results of a prepared statement directly into a dictionary, but I get the error:

```
ValueError: Cursor not available with given criteria: buffered, dictionary, prepared
```

I had read that this is due to the cursor not being buffered by default, but I've enabled buffering with no change in the result.

The full code is below.

```
import mysql.connector

def __init__(self):
    self.mydb= mysql.connector.connect(
        host="host",
        user="user",
        passwd="password",
        database="db",
        buffered=True
    )
    self.cur = self.mydb.cursor(prepared=True, dictionary=True)
    self.fetch_permit = """SELECT PERMIT_ID,BUILDER_BUSINESS_NAME, BUILDER_ZIP_CODE, BUILDER_PHONE_NUMBER
     FROM MASTER_TABLE WHERE permit_id = %s """

def getPermits(self,permit_id):
    permits = self.cur.executemany(self.fetch_permit, permit_id)
    return permits
```

```
info.getPermits(permit_id='1000') # throws error
```

Comment: When inserting a variable into an sql statement at least in oracle you should use ```WHERE permit_id = :id``` try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately no change.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution, but I was able to fix the issue by changing the mySQL library I'm using:

`import pymysql`

Then I changed the cursor:

`self.mydb.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)`

Working as expected now.